# Constructing a map from a vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
["Config" "{}" "Auth" "{}" "Other" "{}"]
```

I'd like to take each key value pair and turn it into the following map:

```
{"Config" "{}", "Auth" "{}", "Other" "{}"}
```

How can I do this with Clojure?  Is there a built in function that does this?

Comment: Just got an answer already, `(apply assoc {} ["Config" "{}" "Auth" "{}" "Other" "{}"])`.  Is there one better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) to apply the map constructor of desired type to the vector, ie :

```
(apply hash-map ["Config" "{}" "Auth" "{}" "Other" "{}"])
```

**edit**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000843/642340) you can get different map types depending on the way you evaluate `{}`, so use the map constructor suitable to your needs.

**edit**

Looking at [this](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-944) the different object types returned by literal `{}` appears to be a bug.

Comment: Thank you, well done!  Leaving question open a bit longer, I don't like accepting answers too early in case someone missed something.

Comment: "If you want to emulate exactly what `{}` does, use `array-map` instead of `hash-map`." As currently implemented, a literal map `{}` expression with constant keys and values would also be parsed as hash-map (although confusingly evaluated as an array-map). Note that the key order of the literal `{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}` is not respected (in version 1.5).

Comment: @A.Webb I was suggested by `(type x)` result. Why does it give different values then? Due to that confusing evaluation?

Comment: @A.Webb you're right, and it is indeed evaluated as array-map. Edited the answer. It there any reason for this behavior?

Comment: Try `(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})`. Then, `(type m) ;=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap`, but  `(type (eval m)) ;=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`. And `(second m) => [:c 3]`. I am not convinced this is intentional.

Comment: Found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000843/642340), which digs a bit deeper into it, but doesn't really answer the question 'why?'. It looks like compiling clj will result in array-map. Definitely looks like unintentional to me.

Comment: I also rambled on about this phenomena at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18468232/1756702). Might be worth searching the [issues log](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ), but I try to be in the habit of being explicit when I care about key order.

Comment: @A.Webb looks like [this report](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-944) talks about a similar issue.

Comment: Array maps will be created by shorter literals. Array maps are promoted to hash maps when above a certain size. They have the same behaviors, it is a performance optimization, you get the one that performs better for the current data size.

Comment: @noisesmith how come then `(def m {:a 1}) (class m)` and `(class {:a 1})` yield different results? The size of the map doesn't change in these two. (clojure 1.5.1)

Comment: oddly: `(= (do (def n {:a 1}) (class n)) (let [n {:a 1}] (class n)))` returns true (in this case the def generates an arraymap)

Comment: My guess is that if you are counting on an arraymap staying an arraymap you are doing clojure wrong (it is an optimization, but does not change the behavior of non-perverse code), and through either oversight or a desire to keep the code base simpler the arraymap optimization is not used for top level non byte-compiled forms.